# html tag to show changeline beside the textarea tag

Tags: php, html, textarea

My HTML code in add form.

```
<textarea id="aboutme" rows="6"></textarea>
```

I entered in the textarea :

```
Hi.
My name is Kevin.

Nice to meet you.
```

My edit form

```
<textarea id="aboutme" name="aboutme" rows="6"><?php echo (isset($item["aboutme"])) ? htmlspecialchars($item["aboutme"]) : "" ;?></textarea>
```

All works fine, except when in my other page, I just want to view. I do :

```
<span>?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['aboutme'])?></span>
```

Well, the **changeline is removed** inside the  `span`  tag. Do I MUST use `textarea` tag inside my view page ? I just don't think that others do it with textarea tag. Is there any other tag available just to view with changeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ignores line breaks. At its simplest, the solution here is to run it through `nl2br`.

```
<span><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($item['aboutme'])) ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean "newline", not "changeline".

In HTML, newlines (and any other whitespace) is collapsed into a single, horizontal space. You can override this with CSS. Something like this would work:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['aboutme']); ?>/div>
```

Comment: Your solution work, but I'll go with simpler one ceejayoz mentioned. Thx man ~

Comment: You should understand the difference between the two answers, and not just "the other one's shorter". My answer will also allow you to use tab characters, multiple spaces, etc. as much as you want, while the other one *only* allows newlines. It's up to you to decide which you want.

Comment: Yeah I know. I figured that I only need newline anyway.